How many ways can we travel from the r-th entry of the row n any member of row n-k where you can only move upwards?
If we have a pascal triangle and we are standing  the $r-$th entry of the row $n$ (entries are $0,1,2,3,4,\dots, n$) Given an integer $1<k\le n$ How many ways can we travel from the $r-$th entry of the row $n$  to any member of row $n-k$ where you can only move upwards like this:


10 can go to 6 , 4. 6 can go to 3 ,3.  4 can go to 3 and 1. In this scenario where $n=5, \ r=2 , \ k=2$ there are four different ways.

int brute_force(int n , int k){
    int dp[k + 1][n];
    memset(dp , 0 , sizeof dp);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) dp[0][i] = 1; 
    for(int lvl = 0; lvl < k;  lvl++){
        for(int i = 0; i < n - lvl; ++i){
            if(i - 1 >= 0) dp[lvl + 1][i - 1] += dp[lvl][i];
            dp[lvl + 1][i] += dp[lvl][i];
        }
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n - k; ++i) ans += dp[k][i];
    return ans;
}

It is easy to  see that if $k \le \min{r, n-r}$ there are $2^k$ ways to travel to any elements of the row $n-k$. I tried to find a formula to find the ways to travel to the row $n-k$ where $\min{r, n-r}< k<\le \max{r, n-r}$ or when $k< \max{r, n-r}$ but I failed to find the closed form.

Number of ways to go from $(n, r)$ to $(n-k, i)$ is $\binom{k}{r-i}$ (where $\binom{a}{b}$ for $b<0$ is 0). You can prove this via induction.
Then our answer is simply $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{k}{r-i} = \sum_{i=\max(r+k-n, 0)}^{\min(r, k)} \binom{k}{i}$$
From above, if $r+k-n \le 0$ and $r \ge k$ ( or $k \le \min(n-r, r)$), then we have the answer as $2^k$.
But AFAIK, there is no closed form formula for the general form, but atleast it should be more efficient to compute in $\mathcal{O}(k)$ time than your DP solution of $\mathcal{O}(nk)$ time.

If you move upwards, you can go left or right. For example, the first step goes to $\binom {n-1}{r-1}$ if you go left or $\binom{n-1}r$ if you go right.
So, if you want to go to $\binom{n-k}j$, then $r-k\le j\le r$, otherwise the number of paths is $0$, because it is imposiible.
Let's code the path like this: for example LLRR means that you move twice left, twice right. The number of L's is exactly $k-j$. But the number of ways to rearrange $j$ L's and $k-j$ R's is precisely $\binom kj$.
In other words, you can 'flip' upside-down the triangle of possible paths from $r$-th row, $n$-th entry, to any entry of $r-k$-th row and move it to the top (only the shape, leave the numbers alone). You'll have the solutions at the base.
